# Как задать всем блокам высоту, как у самого низкого из них?

Tags: html, css

Есть контейнер, а в нем 3 блока с разной высотой. Высота блока зависит от контента.

Как задать всем блокам высоту, как у самого низкого из них?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ru9eLdp/5/)

```css
.wrapper{
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  background:lightgrey;
}
.item{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background:green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как ты им задашь высоту как меньшему из них, если в них не будет влезать текст?

Comment: overflow: scroll; Там будет разный контент(не только текст).

Comment: "Самого низкого" - самого низко расположенного(красного) или самого короткого(зеленого)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allDivs = $('.item');
    var dvSmallest = allDivs[0];
    $(allDivs).each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() < $(dvSmallest).height()) 
            dvSmallest = $(this);
    });
    $('.item').height(dvSmallest.height());
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width:620px;
  height:200px;
  background:lightgrey;
}
.item{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  overflow:auto;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background:green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content c324ontent</div>
</div>
```

Как-то так

Comment: а высоты у всех разные - что-то Ваш скрипт не алё

Comment: Немного подправил код, так лучше?

Comment: лучше, определённо :)

Comment: Что-то еще не выполняет вашей задачи?

Comment: А это не моя задача, я - сторонний наблюдатель.

Comment: С jquery кто-угодно сможет. А через css разве нельзя решить мою задачу?

Comment: @РусланГохгалтер, нельзя. Только если задать жёстко какую-то высоту блокам. А на лету высчитывать высоту наименьшего блока и задавать её другим блокам через css невозможно.

Answer (score 6):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var arr = [];
   $('.item').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).height()); 
   });

   $('.item').height(Math.min.apply(Math, arr)); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  background:lightgrey;
}
.item{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background:green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если самый низкий, вы имеете ввиду по расположению, то можно сверстать на флексах:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
  background:lightgrey;
}
.item{
  width:200px;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background:green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
  <div class="item">content content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content contentcontent content content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "самого низкого" - это, скорее всего, самого маленького (раз для больших будет использован overflow: scroll), так что на чистом css тут не сделать